# A girl who transcends time

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, apocalypse

I remember quite a bit, but can't seem to find the title or (female) author.

- A girl accompanies her father as he captains a mission to travel at near-light speed in order to experience the effects of time dilation and return to Earth 100 years into its future.
- She leaves behind her boyfriend (Tal or Tel or something), who promises he'll find a way to stay with her despite the time travel that will render him, well, dead before her return.
- She's accompanied by a close friend who is deaf but lip-reads and speaks so well as to occasionally fool others into believing she is hearing. They spend a lot of time in the ship's garden.
- I believe he ends up either getting on a different ship to survive into the future via time dilation, or else having himself frozen.
- Either way, if I recall correctly, Earth isn't doing well at all by the time the mission with the girl returns. There's been a war or some other disaster.
- There's an extended period of vague, ambiguous, existential crap in which the girl (now a woman) eventually ends up transferring her consciousness into her own daughter, presumably in order to go on living.
- Everything wraps up somehow and the girl and her boyfriend walk together hand in hand on a desolate planet into the sunset near the end of time.

It was all really rather trashy and silly, I remember, and took itself entirely way too seriously, but I'd like to at least know what it was so I could read it again. Either it'll be worth a laugh, or it'll turn out to be surprisingly good.

Comment: Jon Purdy, I'm interested in what details you got right.  When you get a chance, could you post a comment about it?

Comment: Was actually looking for this for pretty much the same reason.  Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think this is it, but it's been a long time since I read it so I'll throw it out anyways... there are some similarities, and it's possible one or both of us might not remember the details exactly. :)

[*The Starlight Crystal*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11041) by [Christopher Pike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Pike_%28author%29).

Short trashy novella about a girl who transcends time on a space ship that flies at near relativistic speeds. The story starts with her meeting a mysterious older woman, and then later on she's the last human alive, throws the ship into overdrive, and actually loops back around in time and meets herself...

I do vaguely recall something about a boy being involved.

EDITED TO ADD: An [Amazon review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671550292) says the boyfriend's name is Tem. Maybe this is it. :)

Comment: This is it, thanks! It is (and will be) funny to see which details I remembered correctly and which I totally blew.

Comment: Whoa!  You mean there's actually someone named Christopher Pike who writes SF?  Is he in a wheel chair?  Was he ever a captain?

Comment: Actually he's best known for trashy teenage horrors and romance. I picked up a bunch of his stuff, including this, on the cheap at Building 19 (discount chain in Massachusetts) when I was a kid. This book is a major departure from his usual fare.